# Is this method thread safe

Tags: c#

Is this method thread safe?
there are no global variables

```
public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string d)
{
    lock (LockObj)
    {
        return Math.Round(decimal.Parse(d), 2);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
My assumption is that 2 threads gets inside the method, with 2 different values and one can get out before the other, I guess this is a bad assumption, can someone explain?

Comment: Can you expand on what makes you think it might not be?

Comment: This method is thread-safe without any locking. With the lock, it might even deadlock.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How could it deadlock?

Comment: @xanatos - you're right, this code couldn't cause a deadlock. It could get caught up in one. I was drawing attention to the unknown scope and usage of LockObj.

Comment: _"My assumption is that 2 threads gets inside the method"_ It is possible, but should not cause any problem because each thread would deal with its own variable `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method would be thread safe without the lock statement:

```
public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string d)
{
    return Math.Round(decimal.Parse(d), 2);
}
```

There is no shared state or resource, so there's nothing that needs to be protected with a lock.  By adding the lock you actually make it impossible to execute this method in parallel, since the lock guarantees that only one thread can execute the contained code at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a bad understanding of how threads works.

Every time `ConvertToDecimal` is called, a new variable `d` is created on the stack: this is true for all local variables (variables created inside a method) in C#.

This means that every thread which calls `ConvertToDecimal` gets its own `string d` instance and, of course, the same happens in `Math.Round`. If two threads calls the method, there will be two `string d` variables alive and each thread will have access only to its own `d`.

So, there is no need for the lock:

```
public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string d)
{
    return Math.Round(decimal.Parse(d), 2);
}
```

In fact, as Kyle pointed out, by putting the lock in there you make it impossible to execute the method in parallel, because every time a thread reach this line of code: `lock (LockObj)`, it will check if there is any other thread owning the lock for that object and if there is, it will stop execution until the lock is available.

Notice that even if you're trying to access a shared resource you do not necessarily need to use locks; if all access to that resource is a read operation (constants, for example), you may let all threads read it concurrently without locking and it will be fine.